# How to redirect to a login page if Flutter API response is unauthorized?

Tags: flutter, go, dart, jwt

I am building a Flutter app which uses a Golang API to fetch data. The API will return a 401 unauthorized if the JWT token is not valid. How can I redirect to a login page on any API call if the response status is 401?

Here is my flutter code:

main.dart

```
void main() async {

  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  Provider.debugCheckInvalidValueType = null;

  AppLanguage appLanguage = AppLanguage();
  
  await appLanguage.fetchLocale();
  
  runApp(MyApp(
    appLanguage: appLanguage,
  ));

}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  
  final AppLanguage appLanguage;

  MyApp({this.appLanguage});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return  MultiProvider(
          
                  providers: providers,

                  child: MaterialApp(
                            
                      localizationsDelegates: [
                         AppLocalizations.delegate,
                         GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
                         GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
                      ],
          
                  initialRoute: RoutePaths.Login,
                  onGenerateRoute: Router.generateRoute,
                  )        
               );
        }  
}
```

tables.dart

```
class Tables extends StatelessWidget {

  const Tables({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return BaseWidget<TablesModel>(
    
        model: TablesModel(api: Provider.of(context, listen: false)),
    
        onModelReady: (model) => model.fetchTables(),
    
        builder: (context, model, child) => model.busy

            ? Center(

                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              
              )
        
            : Expanded(
               
                 child: GridView.builder (
---
```

tables_model.dart

```
class TablesModel extends BaseModel {
  
  Api _api;

  TablesModel({@required Api api}) : _api = api;

  List<Tbl> tables;

  Future fetchTables() async {
    setBusy(true);
    tables = await _api.getTables();
    setBusy(false);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    print('Tables has been disposed!!');
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

api.dart

```
Future<List<Tbl>> getTables() async {
    
    var tables = List<Tbl>();

    try {

        var response = await http.get('$_baseUrl/tables/list');

        var parsed = json.decode(response.body) as List<dynamic>;
    
        if (parsed != null) {

           for (var table in parsed) {
    
               tables.add(Tbl.fromJson(table));
    
           }
        }

    } catch (e) {print(e); return null;}

    return tables;
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you already have a `MaterialApp` in your tree and the named routes registered, this should be as simple as adding a call to push your login page around the same time you get the response.

First, you should modify `getTables` to check `response` for the status code with `statusCode` property of the [`Response`](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/Response-class.html) object and shown with the following code block:

```dart
var response = await http.get('$_baseUrl/tables/list');

if(response.statusCode == 401) {
  //Act on status of 401 here
}
```

Now that you have a way of checking when the response has a status code of 401, you can navigate to your login page with the `Navigator`. The `Navigator` needs `BuildContext`, so that must be passed to the `getTables` function.

This involves modifying `getTables` to be:

```dart
Future<List<Tbl>> getTables(BuildContext context) async {
```

and `fetchTables` needs a similar change:

```dart
Future fetchTables(BuildContext context) async {
```

Then, where these methods are called, you pass `context` down:

*In `Tables`*

```dart
model.fetchTables(context)
```

*In `TablesModel`*

```dart
Future fetchTables(BuildContext context) async {
  setBusy(true);
  tables = await _api.getTables(context);
  setBusy(false);
}
```

and finally in `getTables`, you use the passed `context` to use the `Navigator`:

```dart
Future<List<Tbl>> getTables(BuildContext context) async {
  var tables = List<Tbl>();
  try {
      var response = await http.get('$_baseUrl/tables/list');

      //Check response status code
      if(response.statusCode == 401) {
        Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(RoutePaths.Login);//Navigator is used here to go to login only with 401 status code
        return null;
      }

      var parsed = json.decode(response.body) as List<dynamic>;

      if (parsed != null) {
         for (var table in parsed) {
             tables.add(Tbl.fromJson(table));
         }
      }

  } catch (e) {print(e); return null;}
  return tables;
}
```

Instead of `Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(RoutePaths.Login);`, you could use `Navigator.pushNamed(context, RoutePaths.Login);` if you prefer, but as you can read at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55548153/flutter-navigator-ofcontext-pop-vs-navigator-popcontext-difference), they internally do the same thing.

Now when there is a status code of 401, a user will be navigated to the login screen.

Comment: Fantastic code. I had incorrectly assumed that I wouldn't get context in the API. Bonus points coming.