# how to redirect the user to the login page if the token has expired

Tags: flutter, dart, authentication

hello I have a case where when the user token expires the user does not switch to the loginPage page, even though I have set it here.
how do i solve this problem thanks.

[image]

i set it on splashscreen if token is not null then go to main page and if token is null then go to login page.
but when the token expires it still remains on the main page

```
Future<void> toLogin() async {
    Timer(
      const Duration(seconds: 3),
      () async {
        SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        String? token = prefs.getString(Constant.token);
        Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(
          context,
          token != null ? AppRoute.mainRoute : AppRoute.loginRoute,
          arguments: token,
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

and function when user login

```
CustomButtonFilled(
                                  title: 'Login',
                                  onPressed: () async {
                                    final prefs =
                                        await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
                                    prefs.setString(Constant.token, '');
                                    if (nimController.text.isEmpty ||
                                        passwordController.text.isEmpty) {
                                      showError('NIM/Password harus diisi');
                                    } else {
                                      setState(() {
                                        isLoading = true;
                                      });
                                      User? user = await userProvider.login(
                                          nimController.text,
                                          passwordController.text);
                                      setState(() {
                                        isLoading = false;
                                      });
                                      if (user == null) {
                                        showError('NIM/Password tidak sesuai!');
                                      } else {
                                        userProvider.user = user;
                                        Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                                          context,
                                          '/main',
                                          (route) => false,
                                        );
                                      }
                                    }
                                  },
                                ),
```

and this call api

```
Future<User?> login(String nim, String password) async {
    String url = Constant.baseURL;
    try {
      var body = {
        'username': nim,
        'password': password,
      };
      var response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse(
          '$url/login_mhs',
        ),
        body: body,
      );
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final token = jsonDecode(response.body)['data']['access_token'];
        //Ini mulai nyimpen token
        await UtilSharedPreferences.setToken(token);
        print(token);
        // print(await UtilSharedPreferences.getToken());
        return User.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      throw Exception();
    }
  }
```

Comment: In this case, you also need to store token expiry date in the shared preferences and check in splash screen if that date is in the past or not and if that date is in the past then you redirect to login or else on home screen. Main reason behind doing this is that even if your token has expired it won't get removed from the shared preference on it's own and you manually need to remove that if you get 401 or unauthorized response from any api.

Comment: i think you need to create one base api class there you can handle all the api responses from one class and set condition on status code if you get status code 401 (Token expiration) then Navigate to login screen.  it will done your work easy from every screen or api you dont have to do such code every time.

Comment: i've update
how do i solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can just make your own HTTP client using Dio and add Interceptor to automatically regenerate idToken if expired using the refreshToken given.

Http client gives an error if the refreshToken also gets expired.

In that case, just navigate to the login screen.

Full code for adding interceptor and making own HTTP client is given below

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';

import '../utils/shared_preference.dart';

class Api {
  static Dio? _client;
  static Dio clientInstance() {
    if (_client == null) {
      _client = Dio();
      _client!.interceptors
          .add(InterceptorsWrapper(onRequest: (options, handler) async {
        if (!options.path.contains('http')) {
          options.path = 'your-server' + options.path;
        }
        options.headers['Authorization'] =
            'Bearer ${PreferenceUtils.getString('IdToken')}';
        return handler.next(options);
      }, onError: (DioError error, handler) async {
        if ((error.response?.statusCode == 401 &&
            error.response?.data['message'] == "Invalid JWT")) {
          if (PreferenceUtils.exists('refreshToken')) {
            await _refreshToken();
            return handler.resolve(await _retry(error.requestOptions));
          }
        }
        return handler.next(error);
      }));
    }
    return _client!;
  }

  static Future<void> _refreshToken() async {
    final refreshToken = PreferenceUtils.getString('refreshToken');
    final response = await _client!
        .post('/auth/refresh', data: {'refreshToken': refreshToken});

    if (response.statusCode == 201) {
      // successfully got the new access token
      PreferenceUtils.setString('accessToken', response.data);
    } else {
      // refresh token is wrong so log out user.
      PreferenceUtils.deleteAll();
    }
  }

  static Future<Response<dynamic>> _retry(RequestOptions requestOptions) async {
    final options = Options(
      method: requestOptions.method,
      headers: requestOptions.headers,
    );
    return _client!.request<dynamic>(requestOptions.path,
        data: requestOptions.data,
        queryParameters: requestOptions.queryParameters,
        options: options);
  }
}
```

---

```
Dio client = Api.clientInstance();
var resposne = (hit any request);
   if(error in response is 401){
  //it is sure that 401 is because of expired refresh token as we 
  //already handled idTokoen expiry case in 401 error while 
  //adding interceptor.
navigate to login screen for logging in again.
}
```

Please accept the solution if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If your session expire feature has some predefine interval or logic than you have to implement it in splash screen and based on that you can navigate user further. Otherwise you want to handle it in API response only you have add condition for statusCode 401.

```
checkSessionExpire(BuildContext context)
   if (response.statusCode == 200) { 
      //SuccessWork
   } else if (response.statusCode == 401) {
      //SessionExpire
   } else {
      return null
   }
}
```

Comment: https://pastebin.com/NrTy2y30
Undefined name 'context'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.

Comment: You have to pass BuildContext as function parameter to use it, I have update the code. Please check.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ibj11EXDkrkTO0y_fgK7fFqNGpJ_vQHb/view?usp=sharing

Comment: https://pastebin.com/cLUn83ac
still getting the error, how do i fix it or maybe am i putting it wrong

Comment: In your login function you have to pass buildContext. In my code checkSessionExpire is function name. Remove it from your code and add context in your login function. i.e. Future<User?> login (String nim, String password, BuildContext context)

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1H7tpVzsmpAMqYrMJeYcJEy1FoQStaBio/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Right, pass context there. await userProvider.login(nimController.text, passwordController.text, context)

Comment: the result is still the same, when my token expires it doesn't go to the loginPage page

Comment: Trace the response, are you getting 401 response code? If yes add some log in if condition to check does that line of code satisfy the condition or not. Than add your routing code in if else condition - else if (response.statusCode == 401) { // here add some log }

Comment: how, I'm a bit confused here

Comment: by using print statement or breakpoints you can easily debug your response status and code lines,

Comment: I have tried the result is 401 not authorized, and does not move pages

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63271031/how-to-redirect-to-a-login-page-if-flutter-api-response-is-unauthorized